# Post video in getStream activity

Tags: getstream-io

Could you please explain how we can post resources like videos in the Getstream.io API. From the documentation I am aware how we can store text in a feed. I need to know how we can upload images/videos in stream feed.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can not store resources like images or videos on the Getstream.io API, instead you should store references to the resources located either in your own storage or on a third party video/image hosting service. Use the `object` field of the activity or a custom field to store the reference, read more about fields that are allowed for an activity in the [documentation](http://getstream.io/docs/#add-remove-activities).

When you retrieve activities from the Getstream.io API you are responsible for retrieving the actual videos/objects referenced in the object fields.

Comment: S3 is a very good way to store large items such as videos/images. Every file stored in S3 has a unique HTTP link reference.

Answer (score 0):

GetStream offers some great [React JS](https://getstream.io/react-activity-feed/tutorial/) and [React Native](https://getstream.io/react-native-activity-feed/tutorial/) components that allow image uploads off the shelf.

The specific component that allows image uploads for React JS is called the [StatusUpdateForm](https://getstream.github.io/react-activity-feed/#!/StatusUpdateForm). This component also allows file uploads and emoji selections out of the box. If you want to allow video uploads, as previously mentioned, you can upload the video to your server's disk or a third party storage solution (like AWS S3) and create a custom field in your activity that references that video link or you can customize the component to allow video uploads.

FWIW, users can currently post a YouTube or Vimeo link in a post and it will bring up the embedded version of the video.